# How to stretch jasper report page dynamically

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating invoice mgt system where i need to get a customer bill.I create invoice report using Jasper report cutom page width: 80 height:220

Its perfectly working on small list of items

[image]

But when table list items are bigger the page is not stretching and the data's are gone

[image]

Is there any way to stretch the page as the content grows , I am going to use the thermal printer to print the report

Comment: You're using a `Table` for this instead of the report `Datasource`?  Have you tried the `Ignore Pagination` option, since paging is irrelevant in an invoice.  But it might be worth while removing the added Table and using the Datasource directly?

Comment: Its not about the table. without table also the page is not stretching and there is not 2nd page

Comment: I solved the issue by adding isIgnorePagination="true" to the JasperReport tag